# get unique records based on string

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have a table that has records like below.

Table:

```
ID      Name            Value
1       xxx AA           10
2       yyy B            20
3       AA zzz           11
4       xxx B            20
5       kkk C            30
6       qqq (AA) ZZ      10 
7        AA              10
```

I would like to get common records and add values of those records.
The expected output table is:

TableOut

```
ID      Name    Value
1       AA        41
2       B         40
3       C         30
```

The above is just examples of few records. However, the table has more than 100 records and it is possible that, 
in future, records will be added dynamically. 
**Note:** I'm OK, if it picks up sub string those are duplicate and read this as single records.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: How do you determine where the commonality is between records?  What have you already tried?

Comment: Are you not aggregating on the value of the second "word" in the column `Name`? If you think like that, then you should be able to easily achieve this (hint, `SUM`).

Comment: This would be a whole lot more simpler if you had `Name` separated into two columns, one for `xxx` and one for `AA`. But its still possible.

Comment: The output ID doesn't relate to the table ID, right? Also, will the first word always have only 3 characters?

Comment: The problem here is, The position can be anywhere in the string, its not always as 2ns position.

Comment: So, if that's the case, how do you know which word to use?

Comment: That is the challenge.Its like it should pick the duplicate string and make this as one. Just improved my question. Hope I have explained this correctly.

Comment: So the question you need to solve is why your desired output contains AA and not xxx. That is not a question that a computer or strangers can solve for you.

Comment: Those things you like to aggregate (AA, B, C) are they like fixed codes?  Is there some rule that identifies they as a code, for example 1 or 2 capital letters.  Or could a reference table be used for them?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
-- sample data
declare @tbl table (ID int, Name varchar(10), Value int);
insert into @tbl values
(1, 'xxx AA', 10),
(2, 'yyy B', 20),
(3, 'zzz AA', 11),
(4, 'xxx B', 20),
(5, 'kkk C', 30);
-- select query
select row_number() over (order by NewName) ID,
       NewName, 
       sum(Value) 
from (
    select substring(Name, charindex(' ', Name) + 1, len(Name)) NewName,
           Value
    from @tbl
) a group by NewName
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(name, CHARINDEX(' ', name) +1, 20), SUM(Value)
from table
group by SUBSTRING(name, CHARINDEX(' ', name) +1, 20)
```

Comment: This won't work. `GROUP BY name` means that `xxx AA` and `yyy AA` doesn't get grouped (as is the question from OP)

Comment: Sorry... didn't read the question correctly. Check if this query with you want to group by string after the first space character

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
select SUBSTRING(Name, CHARINDEX(' ', Name),3) AS region, SUM(value) as Value 
from example
group by (SUBSTRING(Name, CHARINDEX(' ', Name),3))
```

the First Column is Actually a serial Number

Answer (score 0):

How I'd do it, using `STUFF`:

```
WITH VTE AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES(1,'xxx AA',10),
                (2,'yyy B',20),
                (3,'zzz AA',11),
                (4,'xxx B',20),
                (5,'kkk C',30)) V(ID,[Name],[Value]))
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY N.R) AS ID,
       N.R AS [Name],
       SUM([Value]) AS [Value]
FROM VTE V
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(STUFF(V.[Name],1,CHARINDEX(' ',V.[Name]),''))) N(R)
GROUP BY N.R
ORDER BY N.R;
```